# javascript in Joomla custom module

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have a code generated by "highslide" software and what it does is to create an image gallery.

This code consists of .css  html and javascript.

If I place the htmal code in the Joomla's "index.php" file and then the rest of the file in the root directory then the image gallery is working and is placed in every page in Joomla.

I do not want this. Is there a way of assigning that image gallery to only pages I choose?
Or is there a way to find out what is the index.php main file for that specific page I need to have the gallery and paste the code in there?

I have tried to insert the code in a custom module via the Joomla's editor but when I click on save then it compiles the code and remove certain parts of it and cannot work.
It removes the link to javascript and to css file.

Is there a way without any other third party extension to have that code into the custom module without then Joomla eliminate the half of the code?

Thank you,

Best Regards,

Andreas Achilleos

Comment: You may be able to modify your editor's configuration to allow JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not add things like this to your index.php file. This is Joomla, not a static html website ;)

You have 3 options:

**Option 1** would be to develop your own module and install it on your Joomla site. This option would take the longest amount of time and would require you to get your handy in a bit of coding.

**Option 2** would be to firstly download, install and enable a plugin called [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051). Once done, in the Joomla backend, create a new "Custom Module" and manually add your html code. After, below the big textbox, you will see a button below saying "Insert code". O modal will popup allowing you to add your custom code. Simply add your CSS and JS using the `<style>` and `<script>` tags.

**Option 3** would be to use a pre-built [Image Gallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images) extensions from the Joomla Extensions Directory. There are loads to choose from.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello Lodder,  I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I will try with the sourcerer. Just that the gallery is working in all pages. Can't I interfere and assign the gallery in one page only?  For example, what if I want to change the html and/or the css for a specific page on the site; where are the files located in order to change them?  Thank you

Comment: If you want to change any of the code for the gallery on a different page, you can simply duplicate the module in the Module Manager in the Joomla backend ;) The good thing about keeping it as a module rather than in the index.php is that you can assign a module to any specific page or multiple pages

Comment: OK I think I got some things.  Never the less one last thing. Lets say I want to add a picture in the middle of the a page of my page,  only in one page and I want to do that without the help of modules; can I do that? Where do I place my html/css/js? You know I right click on a page of my Joomla site and choose view page source and it results the following : "http://argyrou.cloudaccess.net/zxvxcbb-cv.html"  I search in the websites database and I cannot find any document listed as that! where is that file?  Thank you, sorry for keep "pushing" the post! Don't thing I have any questions left :)